# Disable SASS from generating vendor specific webkit-keyframe code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

I have this very strange issue, which is baffling. I have my application.scss in which the first directive is

@import "font-awesome.min"

now font-awesome.min.css is the the file which is in plain css and it contains these lines of code somewhere down the line..

```
.fa-spin {
animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear
}

@keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
      transform: rotate(359deg)
  }
}
```

What is happening is that my final browser css contains a new @-webkit-keyframes definition just above the original @keyframes code (also its reference is added to fa-spin property also), although I don't want it,

I just want the plain font-awesome.min.css to be included in the final stylesheet as it is, without any changes.

I have checked carefully for any mixins, which are not related to keyframe directive, and my IDE is not doing anything funny. It is a rails app. Any ideas?

Comment: just to ask, cause it's quite some time i'm not using rails. what problem causes the re-definition of the @-webkit-keyframe? and why souldn't it be present?

Comment: I am looking to generate a valid css3 from my project without vendor prefixes. The original css has only keyframe definition, but when the final output is generated from the sass compiler, it has the added -webkit-keyframes, which i dont want.

Comment: did you download the font-awesome.min.css and cleared out all the unwanted vendor directives? because if i inspect the font-aswesome.css on the site, the fa-spin keyframe, contains also the one with vendor. 

`.fa-spin {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}`
Maybe you have to un-minify the file and clean it from vendor prefixes

Comment: @sissy yes thats the first thing i did, check my question, I checked everything carefully, after that asked the question of how to stop sass from modifying the output css.